# For multipath TCP do you require mptcp on both client and server?

Tags: tcp

Just wondering whether you require both server serving the content and client are to be on a linux kernel with mptcp enabled?

I've read through some articles and they seem to be using a token/connection ID which I presume regular TCP doesn't do. So if that's the case then both server/client need to be on MPTCP isn't it? Or Have I missed something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, both - client and server - need to support MPTCP.

As you said, MPTCP changes the wire format of TCP by adding new TCP options.

Comment: As a side question, do you know if services like Amazon S3 support it? Or more generally about the global support of multipath tcp on servers?

Answer (score 2):

Yes both of them need to have the same to support multi-path. If any of them (client or server) does not have then they act as a regular TCP flow. Mainly, at the beginning of the connection, the (3-way handshake) both of them exchange the information (MP_CAPABLE) that is it possible or not. If possible then the socket Establishes another flow which is mainly done by Path Manager. For more details (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6824)
Though this question is asked almost 3 years ago, maybe it would be helpful for others now.